# Bootstrapping SOFR curve and Swap Payment Lag

Tags: quantlib, curve-fitting, ois-swaps

Can someone provide me an intuitive explanation of how discount factors are bootstrapped for SOFR when Swaps are trading with payment delay/ lag (e.g. of 2 business days).

I can intuitively derive the discount factors when the payment lag is zero e.g.

| Trade Date | Value Date | Tenor | Maturity | Swap Rate | Pay Lag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Feb 2023 | 3 Feb 2023 (T+2) | 1M | 3 Mar 2023 | 3.5% | 0 |

Since Payment Lag = 0, the cash flow date is 3 Mar 2023.

Now the discount factor from 3-Feb-2023 to 3-Mar-2023 equals
1/(1+3.5%*28/360) ==> 0.99728516

This would then get multiplied with the discount factor for 3 Feb 2023 to arrive at the final discount factor from 1-Feb-2023 to 3-Mar-2023.

However, **when the payment lag is 2 days**, then the Cash Flow Date is 7 Mar 2023, although accrual period remains the same (3 Feb 2023 to 3 Mar 2023). **How would the discount factors get calculated, in this scenario ?**

Appreciate any clarity from your side. I hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

The convexity adjustments for payment lags are usually so tiny (see [Why is there a convexity adjustment if the payment date differs from Libor end date?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/43085/why-is-there-a-convexity-adjustment-if-the-payment-date-differs-from-libor-end-d)) that we can ignore them for the bootstrapping. So you only need to worry about the accrual periods etc

Comment: Thanks river_rat, will ponder upon this. Got a link to another thread ..https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/64342/rfr-boostrapping-using-rfr-ois-is-convexity-adjustment-technically-necessary?rq=1 appears relevant to my question.

Comment: Convexity adjustments are small/negligible for a non-delayed versus a delayed payment swap, that is true. But this does not mean that swaps with different payment lags have the *same* mid-market price. It is important to correctly account for the real timing of cashflows.

Comment: True but for typical curves and a typical payment delay of 2 days we are talking a difference in mids of 0.17bps at the 10yr point?